# Paypal Pro Hosted Sandbox credit cards - nothing works

Tags: paypal-sandbox, credit-card

Has anyone ever managed to successfully process a credit card transaction on PayPal Pro Hosted sandbox?

I have used the test card generated in the sandbox profile, test cards from the old PayPal 'documentation', test cards generated from multiple card number generators.. nothing works

Message on the PayPal page is always:

> We’re sorry, we can’t complete this payment with the selected card at
>   this time. Please try another card.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it only works if you turn of the extra card verification in the sandbox merchant profile